# build an if statment using max and min

Tags: math, logic

Well,

My first question here.

Is it possible to build an "If" statement using only "max" and "min" statements?

The problem that i have Is that I need to compare 2 numbers (A and B)and see if  B > 1.1 x A. If that happens I pick B if not, I pick A .

Any idea?

Comment: Yeah, it's simple.  `if B > 1.1 x A I pick B if not, I pick A`.  Of course, there's absolutely no way to answer your question, because we don't know if you're soldering logic gates or if you're coding in lolcat.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please expand your question to specify the language you are working in, and what you have tried so far as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If, as tagged, your question is a logic question then I think it belongs here: https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks is a propietary language so a solution in any language can work.

Comment: @PédeLeão oh, well, that's much clearer now.  You should provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks for a very fast answer it is a propietary language so a solution in any language can work for this reason I'm asking for the logic behind it. lets say that I have the function z=Max(x,y) wher z is the max of x and y and the function z =min(x,y) where z pick the minimum value between x and y. I have also the common operators "+", "-", "*", "/" and "-" How I can construct the question that I posted?

Comment: Are `A`, `B` positive?

Comment: max and min are continuous functions. So are their compositions with themselves and other arithmetic operations.

Your desired function is not continuous, it has jumps from A to 1.1*A if the value of B is varied. So it seems that your quest can not be solved by simple means. There might be ways if one were to include discontinuous functions like floor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An if statement, whether in pure (order-invariant) logic or in procedural logic, will work on boolean statements only.  That means true or false.  A min or max function returns a number, not a true/false value.  So the short answer to your question is no, it is not possible to build an if statement using max and min return values.

Now, in the details of your question, you shed a little more light on what you want.  What's confusing though is how max and min enters into the equation.  B > 1.1*A requires no Max and Min processing, so are you using Max and Min functions to arrive at B and at A?  If so, then simply process them first, and then plug them into that equation.

And because "greater than" and "less than" comparions DO return true/false values, you're in luck.  Just use that in your "if" statement.  Here is some pseudo-code.

```
max1 = 25
max2 = 72
min1 = 95
min2 = 80

A = Max(max1,max2)
B = Min(min1,min2)

O = NULL

if B > 1.1 * A then 
    set O = B
else 
    set O = A
end if
```

When the output of an if statement is a value, as opposed to a command, as you seem to desire, some languages use the "elvis" operator, which makes things prettier.  Using it, you would just write:

```
O = B > 1.1 * A ? B : A
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers. I suspected that the problem doesnt have a solution but allways do you have a hope.

Comment: @Eperezj if you accept that the answer doesn't have a solution precisely because of what I stated above, please accept my answer so that future readers can be informed.

Comment: Done! pwilcox Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If your logical operators accept non-boolean value, you could do it as follows:

```
n = Max(B - 1.1*A, 0)
output = Max(B*(n && n), A)
```